# Re-rendering of Backbone.Marionette template on trigger event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, scope, marionette

I'm using Backbone Marionette to render layouts on my page.  However, after the initial rendering, I try to re-render one of the partial templates on the page after issuing a refund by triggering ("RefModal:PayRef"). Unfortunately, I end up with the following error:
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined'
After some debugging, it appears I no longer have access to totalRegion as "that.totalRegion" becomes undefined hence the error ("that" still appears to have scope however).

If anyone could help with a way to access "totalRegion" on the second, third, fourth, etc, triggering of "RefModal:PayRef" that would be awesome. I hope this is enough information to go on.

```
views.OrderDTLayout = Marionette.Layout.extend({
        template: "orderManagement/bb-total-layout.dust",
        className: "bbMgmt",
        regions: {
            totalRegion: "#bb-total-region",
            shippingRegion: "#bb-global-shipping-region"
        },
        events: {
            "click #bb-cancel": "showCancelModal",
            "keypress #bb-cancel": "handleShowCancelModal"
        },
        initialize: function () {
            var that = this;
            var spinnerMod =  mad.App.module("Seller.OrdMgmt.Spinner");
            this.loadingController = new spinnerMod.Controller();

            mad.App.vent.on("RefModal:PayRef", function (orderModel) {
                var totalView = mad.App.Seller.OrdMgmt.OrdTotals.Controller.createPackageOrderTotals(orderModel);
                that.totalRegion.show(totalView);
            });

//triggered from separate file
mad.App.vent.trigger("RefModal:PayRef", order)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try binding the context of this to your event handler:

```
mad.App.vent.on("RefModal:PayRef", function (orderModel) {
    var totalView = mad.App.Seller.OrdMgmt.OrdTotals.Controller.createPackageOrderTotals(orderModel);
    that.totalRegion.show(totalView);
}, this);
```

Notice **this** passed in as the last argument.  Then you can access `this.totalRegion.show(view)`

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the fix.  In the end I ended up having to pass: 

  `mad.App.vent.on("RefModal:PayRef", function (orderModel) {  
    var totalView =     mad.App.Seller.OrdMgmt.OrdTotals.Controller.createPackageOrderTotals(orderModel);  
    this.show(totalView);  
}, this.totalRegion);`